# setting up permissions for Virtual Host on Centos 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host

I am following a book's chapter on setting up Virtual Hosts. The process is:

1.create a file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.conf`
2.set its content to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/example/
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally

3.execute `apachectl configtest` and `apachectl graceful`

This appears to be working. But more commonly, `DocumentRoot` is located in `/home/exampleuser/public_html`. This path is problematic to apache group so I modified permissions to

```
drwxr-x--- 3 exampleuser apache 4096 Feb  8 09:50 exampleuser
drwxr-xr-x 2 exampleuser apache 4096 Feb  8 09:55 public_html
```

where `exampleuser` is the user that to which the the directory belongs and was created with `useradd exampleuser` command.

I also added this code in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and reloaded httpd.service.

```
<Directory “/home/exampleuser/public_html”>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The book doesn't state what is the correct permission configuration so I am wondering if I have done it correctly? Is there a security issue if I leave the permissions as they are now?

httpd error_log file

```
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.453239 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4848] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using example.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.732490 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4848] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.733391 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4848] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.736501 2017] [:warn] [pid 4848] NSSSessionCacheTimeout is deprecated. Ignoring.
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.745349 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4848] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_auth_kerb/5.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_nss/1.0.14 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 08 10:25:55.745375 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4848] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's quotes in config?

```
<Directory “/home/exampleuser/public_html”>
```

Try:

```
<Directory "/home/exampleuser/public_html">
```

And see log into `/var/log`.

Comment: nice catch. I edited it, but I think it didn't change anything. I successfully loaded index.html in public_html before and after changing it. I updated question with error_log file